# What exactly happens when a heavy soldier misses with a rocket shot?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown, xcom-enemy-within

Heavy soldiers usually have a 90% chance when shooting a rocket; or 0% if you try an impossible shoot. So far all my rockets have impacted where they are supposed to, but eventually they will fail. So I have some doubts:

- What happens when rocket fails?
- Where will it land?
- Is it possible to have a friendly fire incident?
- Will enemy rockets fail?
- Can they have friendly fire incidents?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When the shots fail, the rocket will launch in a random trajectory and detonate if it hits something.  Typically the direction the rocket heads will still be in the general vincinity of the original intended target.  This CAN cause friendly fire.

Once you obtain the blaster launcher, your rockets will no longer be able to miss (on top of causing more damage) as they become guided rockets instead.

As for enemy rockets, the only ones that use a similar system are the EXALT agents.  I suppose theoretically they can miss too but typically I don't give them a chance to use their rocket on me so I have limited experience and I've never seen one fail yet.

Comment: Out of interest you say typically in the same direction. Does this mean that they might go off in the opposite direction or something? Just curious because I assumed it would always be a small deviation from the original trajectory...

Comment: @Chris I've never seen them go way off (more than 90 degrees) from the original trajectory but I can't rule out a negative without being able to take a look at the actual game code.

Comment: I don't think I've seen them go more than about 15 degrees off. I am not a big fan of rockets generally though so only have seen a couple of deviations. I just would be very surprised if they coded it so a miss was any more crap than with a gun (where its always closeish), the only difference being it matters where a rocket goes. :) I do see your point but I would probably have been happy to state it as more fact until proven otherwise. ;-)

Comment: Is the blaster launcher definitely 100% to hit? I think I always assumed it had a chance to go wrong in the same way as a rocket, but that I hadn't used it enough to see it happen...

Comment: @Flyto i've never missed with the blaster launcher.  Pretty sure its always 100%

Answer (score 3):

When the shots fail, they will fire at the same level and elevation that you aimed it at, but be off by a fixed angular offset (from RNG seed). This will cause it to explode w/ regular collision rules.

It is thus not only possible to cause friendly fire, but for the heavy to blow him/herself up.

To test this, if you saved right before firing the miss, you can in fact get the rocket to hit completely centered if you compensate for the offset when trying again. Note: this is assuming the Save Scum Second Wave option from Enemy Within is not enabled.

Unsure about exact mechanics of enemy rockets as they don't typically live long enough to try.